# Qt struct of QPolygon

Tags: c++, qt, qpolygon

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
    QPolygon polygon;
    QRect position;
} form;
```

I try to initialize `forms` like below but I got segmentation fault error:

```
int n = 10
forms = (form*) malloc(sizeof(form) * n);
while (n>0) {
   forms[n].position.setRect(0,0,0,0);
   forms[n].polygon=QPolygon(0); //error - segmentation fault
   forms[n].polygon = QPolygon(QRect(x, y, w, h)); //error - segmentation fault
}
```

I try like this also:

```
QPolygon v;
v = QPolygon(QRect(x, y, w, h)); //ok
v = QPolygon(QRect(x, y, w, h)); //ok
sprites[n].polygon = QPolygon(QRect(x, y, w, h)); //error - segmentation fault
```

How can I have a polygone into a struct?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Lines that generates errors are already marked with comments. I obtained those using the debugger. Thanks anyway for the copy-paste guidelines.

Comment: Do you have a backtrace also maybe? Learn how to use your tools please.

Comment: You shouldn't ever use `malloc` for C++ classes. You could use `new` to directly allocate an array, though that is "outdated" style of coding C++, too. If you use `malloc`m you should then use so called "placement new" to initialize your structs. Also, using `typedef` like that is not necessary in C++.

Answer (score 1):

First, define your struct like this in C++:

```
struct form { // note: Qt naming convention would use upper case first letter
    QPolygon polygon;
    QRect position;
};
```

At the end of this answer there is a more modern alternative, but first, to directly fix your 20 years old style C++, write your code like this (you shouldn't, but just so you know how to do it):

For this, lets assume you have

```
form *forms;
```

Then you could make your code not crash, if you wrote it like this:

```
int n = 10
forms = new form[n]; // bad style in modern C++, use std::vector instead
while (n > 0) {
   --n; // indexes go 9..0
   //forms[n].position.setRect(0,0,0,0); // constructor did this
   //forms[n].polygon=QPolygon(0); // constructor did this
   forms[n].polygon = QPolygon(QRect(x, y, w, h));
}
```

Your error *might* have been, because your `QPolygon` and `QRect` instances inside `form` structs were not properly constructed. Hard to say, what you did was undefined behavior, accessing uninitialized memory like that. Additionally, you had `n==10` in your loop's first iteration, which is outside valid index range 0..9, that might have crashed too.

---

Additionally, when you allocate an array with `new`, you *must* also delete it as array, so that array elements get properly destructed:

```
delete[] forms;
```

With modern C++, you wouldn't need to do this, you'd use value types or smart pointers.

---

Finally, a more modern version, which is just all around easier and safer, and you don't need to worry about releasing memory, etc:

```
std::vector<form> forms;


int n = 10
forms = std::vector<form>(n); // assign a vector of length n to forms


while (n > 0) {
    ... contents of the loop are same as above ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're writing C++11, not C, your code should be much simpler. Leverage the language you're using.

`emplace_back` constructs the `Form` instance right inside the vector: it's the fastest way to do it. You could also use `push_back`, but that constructs a temporary that's not cheaply movable.

```
struct Form {
    QPolygon polygon;
    QPoint position; // maybe you meant QRect boundingRect?
    Form(const QPolygon & polygon, const QPoint & position) :
        polygon{polygon}, position{position} {}
    Form() = default;
};

class Class {
    std::vector<Form> forms;
public:
    Class() {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int w = 100;
        int h = 100;
        forms.reserve(20); // avoids copies as the vector grows
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            forms.emplace_back(QRect{x,y,w,h}, QPoint{x,y});
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            forms.push_back({QRect{x,y,w,h}, {x,y}}); // uniform initialization
    }
};
```